# AppleScript to copy files

Tags: file, copy, applescript

I have an Applescript to copy files from one directory to another with replacing files in the destination automatically.  I keep getting an error that Finder can't every file of the source directory.  What am I doing wrong?  Thanks for your input!

```
set source to "Edit System:Users:lisa.reed:Library:Application Support:RenewedVision:ProPresenter5:Playlists:Sanctuary.pro5pl"

set destination to "WorshipMedia:ProPresenter Data:__Playlist_Data"

set source2 to "Edit System:Users:lisa.reed:Documents:ProPresenter5"

set destination2 to "WorshipMedia:ProPresenter Data:__Documents:Sanctuary"

tell application "Finder"
    duplicate file source to folder destination with replacing
    duplicate files of source2 to folder destination2 with replacing
end tell
```

Answer (score 2):

Put the word "folder" in front of source2 in this line...

```
duplicate files of source2 to folder destination2 with replacing
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use **do shell script** command instead of using Finder application as it's more flexible solution

`do shell script "cp /Users/lisa.reed/Documents/ProPresenter5/* <path_to_destination>"`